How do I print the arguments passed to a function when using Python Fire?
I'm using the fire library in Python to create a simple command-line interface (CLI). My setup is as follows:
import fire

def main(a):
    print('hi')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(main)


When I run the script like this:
$ python my_script.py 123

It prints:
hi

What I'd like to do is print the arguments passed to main (in this case 123) before it prints "hi". Is there a way to intercept and print the arguments in fire.Fire(main)?
I've tried modifying the function signature and adding *args, but that changes how the function behaves with Fire.
How can I print the arguments passed to main using Python Fire without changing the logic inside the function?

Attempt:
import fire

class MyWrapper:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def method(*args, **kwargs):
            # Print the arguments passed to the Fire CLI
            print(f"Method: {name}, Args: {args}, Kwargs: {kwargs}")
            # Call the original method
            return getattr(self.target, name)(*args, **kwargs)
        return method

class MyCommands:
    def greet(self, name="World"):
        return f"Hello, {name}!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(MyWrapper(MyCommands))



Just use sys.argv? I suspect that's all Fire does in order to pass those values to main when it calls it.

Doing what you want in your first example should be trivial. Just add print(a). Your second example is a bit more complex. What happens when you run the second example? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not what is the output and what do you want instead?

Isn't this what the "hello world version 2" example in their docs is doing? https://google.github.io/python-fire/guide/#version-2-firefirefn

Try:
def main(a):
    print(f'{a} hi')

I don't have fire installed.

There's always just dumping args and/or kwargs
def example(**kwargs):
    print(f"Supplied kwargs: {kwargs}")
    a = kwargs.get("a")
    print(f"'a' kwarg: {kwargs.get('a')}")

You can also use inspect
import inspect

def example_function(a, b, c=3, d=4):
    # Get information about the current function call [frame]
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    
    # Get the arguments passed to this function
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    
    # Print out the arguments and their values
    for arg in args:
        print(f"{arg} = {values[arg]}")

# Call the function
example_function(1, 2, d=5)

>>> example_function(1, 2, d=5)
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 5

